# NextJS image not resizing images as expected on Next 13

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image

I am **strugling** a lot with NextJS Image component to **load images at the most efficient size for different screens**.

Basically what happens is: all images are loaded apparently at its largest size.

Below there is an image showing the resolution that appears at all screen sizes, with the following Image properties:

```
          alt="alt text"
          sizes="(max-width: 486px) 90vw, 400px"
          fill
          priority={true}
          placeholder="blur"
```

[See the screenshot of the srcsets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woiKN.png)

The main strategy I used was through an img container in a relative position as follows:

```
  position: relative !important;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
```

The Next Image component as follows:

```
        <Image
          src={srcImg}
          alt="alt"
          sizes="(max-width: 486px) 90vw, 400px"
          fill
          priority={true}
          placeholder="blur"
        />
```

Also tried the Image component:

```
        <Image
          src={src}
          alt="alt"
          sizes="(min-width: 520px) 400px, (min-width: 340px) calc(87.5vw - 38px), calc(-100vw + 560px)"
          placeholder="blur"
          priority={true}
          quality={80}
        />
```

I also tried styling the component and other myriad of sizes variations.

Here is my next.config:

```
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
    prependData: `
      @import "@/styles/variables.scss";
      @import "@/styles/scrollbar.scss";
    `,
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['xxx', 'xxx'],
    images: {
      formats: ['image/webp', 'png'],
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 position: relative !important;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
  height: 300px;
```

- in image container use a secific height